# What is the meaning of the 'or' in a axiom or a definition?

Tags: terminology

'A or B' means one or the other or both.

So I think $\{x | x = u$ or $ x = v\}$ can be equal to $\{u\}$ or $\{v\}$ or $\{u, v\}$. 
Similary, I think $\{x | x\in a $ or $ x\in b\}$ can be equal to any subset of $a \cup b$ except empty set.
But actually $\{x | x = u$ or $ x = v\} = \{u, v\}$ and $\{x | x\in a $ or $ x\in b\} = a \cup b$. What am I missing?

Comment: $\{ x \in \mathbb R \mid x = 1 \text{ or } x = 2 \}$ consists of all real numbers $x$ that satisfy either $x = 1$ or $x = 2$.

Comment: @littleO Ok, I got what you said. But I think my interpretation also makes sense. Isn't it? Is their a definition about how to use the term 'or'?

Comment: $\{x|x=u\text{ or }x=v\}$ is the set of ALL $x$ such that $x=u$ or $x=v$. Note that both $u$ and $v$ satisfy this property. So they are both in the set. Similarly, $\{x|x\in A\text{ or }x\in B\}$ is the set of ALL $x$ belonging to either $A$ or $B$ (possibly both). Every element of $A$ and $B$ satisfies this, so you get the whole union $A\cup B$.

Comment: Let $S = \{ x \in \mathbb R \mid x = 1 \text{ or } x = 2 \}$. Does $1$ belong to $S$? Yes, it satisfies the condition necessary to belong to $S$. Does $2$ belong to $S$? Yes, it also satisfies the condition necessary to belong to $S$.

Comment: "But I think my interpretation also makes sense. "  It makes sense, yes, but unfortunately it is incorrect.  You are pre-supposing that there is a number $x$ and that it currently exists and we are being told something about it.  Set notation means the $x$ is a label for all potential values and all possible values are in the set. ... consider $\{x|x\in \mathbb R\}$.  By your interpretation $5 \in \mathbb R$ so $x$ could be $5$.  So the set could be $\{5\}$. That's... consistent but pointless.  Instead the *set* is all *possible* things that $x$ could be. i.e $\{x|x\in \mathbb R\}=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ is variable and is a hypothetical.  It is a place value of everything that could be.   It is not an actual thing and doesn't actually equal anything.

$\{x|x= u$ or $x=v\} = \{$ all possible numbers so long as the number we are considering is either $u$ or $v\}$.

As $u$ is a possible value $u$ must bein the set. And as $v$ is a possible value it is in the set.  Any other value is neither $u,v$ so no other value is in the set.

So the set $\{x|x=u$ or $x=v\}$ is *precisely* $\{u,v\}$.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you're missing is that your example uses the [set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#Sets_defined_by_a_predicate) $\{x|P(x)\}$, which is defined to mean "the set of all objects $x$ for which the sentence $P(x)$ is true". The "or" in your example is part of the $P(x)$ formula - it's incorrect to interpret the expression in a different way (such as the way you might interpret an English sentence with "or" in it).